# Can I call a method in a class that is not part of the class or its parents?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the reason of an error in my project. I think that the topic of this question is the reason. Here's some code that describes the problem:

```
def self.foo()
    content = 10
    return content
end

class MyClass
    def self.bar()
        number = self.foo()
        puts number
    end
end
```

So, is it possible to call the method outside the class from the classmethod inside the class? From what I've tried it doesn't seem to work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should pick another class name and other method names for your example. Something like `MyClass` or `foo` / `bar` / `baz`.

Comment: Like this? Otherwise, feel free to edit so I'll know how to do it right in the future.

Comment: Much better. There already is a class [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Class.html) and also a method [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-method) which could be quite confusing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you use `self` in a class method context means that you want to call it ON the class. Since that method is not defined in that class, you will get an error. If you remove the `self.` part of the invocation, this will succeed.

```
def foo
  10
end

class Bar
  def self.baz
    puts foo
  end
end
```

However, it will work just because of where methods defined in the main scope go. If everything was enclosed in a module, you have to explicitly state where the method is located:

```
module Bong 
  def self.foo
    10
  end

  class Bar
    def self.baz
      puts Bong.foo
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For my project it's enclosed in a module indeed! I'll check your answer out.

Comment: The first example doesn't work unless `foo` is defined as a global function.

Comment: @Ruts. happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
class Class2 
 def self.method()
   content = 10
   return content
 end
end
class Class
  def self.classmethod()
     number = Class2.method()
     puts number
  end
end
```